# TYPO3 11.5 Display a form from 'Form' extension in CustomContentElement

Tags: php, typo3

I make a custom ContentElement, and now I want to add a form made with "Form" extension.

I tried to render my form without controller like in the doc : https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#render-viewhelper

there is the typescript of my contentElement :

```
tt_content {
  myContent =< lib.contentElement
  myContent {
      templateName = MyCustomContentElement
        extbase {
        pluginName = Formframework
        controllerExtensionName = Form
        controllerName = FormFrontend
      }
      dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FlexFormProcessor
        10 {
          field = pi_flexform
          as = flexform
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and I tried to call the viewHelper inside my Template like this :

```
/*
Some html of my Custom content element
*/
<formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="{flexform.form.persistenceIdentifier}" />
```

But I got this error :

```
Tried resolving a template file for controller action "FormFrontend->render" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (FormFrontend/Render.html). The following paths were checked: /MyExt/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/
```

Some ideas to solve my issue please ?

I'm using TYPO3 V11.5

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your contentelement already can save the form in the flexform field.
The easiest way to achive what you want is to first build your custom content element like this:

```
tt_content {
  myContent = COA_INT
  myContent {
    10 = < lib.stdheader
    20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    20 {
      file = EXT:MyExt/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/MyCustomContentElement.html
      dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FlexFormProcessor
        10 {
          field = pi_flexform
          as = flexform
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need a TyposcriptObject like this:

**EDIT:** You need a COA_INT object to avoid caching problems, when you use finishers in your form.

```
lib.myForm = COA_INT
lib.myForm {
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
    template = TEXT
    template.field = persistenceIdentifier
    template.wrap = <formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="|" />
    extbase {
      pluginName = Formframework
      controllerExtensionName = Form
      controllerName = FormFrontend
      controllerActionName = perform
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can pass the persistenceIdentifier to the cObj in your Template like this:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myForm" data="{persistenceIdentifier: flexform.form.persistenceIdentifier}" />
```

This will then render the selected form.

Comment: I tried this I got this error : Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard-> myContent" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/MyContent). The following paths were checked:

I tried to add a folder "Standard" Inside  my folder "ContentElements" and I moved MyContent.html in "Standard" and the error still persist

My content element my content doesn't just contain the form, it has text, buttons If I put the content in "Standard", will typo3 recognize my template?

Comment: Have you followed the steps from the docs to create your contentelement? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#create-a-custom-content-element-type.  Especially the point https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#configure-the-frontend-rendering.

Comment: Why would TYPO3 look for a Template in "Standard/MyContent"? Check your config for that and break everything down to smallest functionality. I tested my answer in TYPO3 11 and it works. So you must have some misconfiguration.

Comment: I edited my post with a working version of my typoscript, now it's working but when I configure a Finisher in the back office of typo3, it doesn't work when I'm using my form in the custom content element, when I put my form in a form content, finishers work perfectly
There are some configuration to do ?

Comment: Seems to be an cache issue. When using a COA_INT object the finishers works proper. But this could maybe cause some performance issues. I updated my answer.

Comment: Would be great, if you could mark the Answer as solved, if it works now. And maybe give it a up :-)